# Finding the closure of A=$\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Finding the closure of A=$\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$.

My attempt: Between every two rational numbers, there is a rational number. That means that for  any arbitrarily small $\epsilon \gt0$, and some $q\in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$  there is $x \notin \mathbb Q$, $x\in [0,1]$ so that $x\in (q-\epsilon, q+\epsilon)$. That means - **and I'm not sure if that's correct and how to show it** - there is a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ so that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=x$.

Therefore, the closure of A is $[0,1]$.

Is this correct? And how do I show my missing step (if it's valid?).

Thanks for any assistance in advance!

Comment: You don't need to find a sequence, just prove there's a number arbitrarily close.

Comment: Such a sequence exists but you don't need it in order to solve this  question. Can you see why it exists using the answer below ?

Comment: Do you really want to say "Between every two rational numbers, there is a rational number" in this context...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $x \in [0,1]$ there are rationals $q$ arbitrarily close to $x$. For each natural number $n$, choose $a_n \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ such that $|x-a_n| < \frac1n$. Then we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = x$.

Answer (score 4):

A point $x \in [0,1]$ is in the closure of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ if and only if every open set $U$ containing $x$ intersects $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.

Take an open set $U$ containing $x$. There exists an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $x \in(a,b) \subseteq U$ (why ?). This interval $(a,b)$ surely intersects $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ (why ?).

Comment: "This interval (a,b) surely intersects Q∩[0,1] (why ?)." I can't see why....

Comment: $(a,b) \subseteq U \subseteq [0,1]$, right ? If $(a,b)$ doesn't intersect $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$, then $(a,b)$ is an open interval containing no rational numbers. Is it possible ?

Comment: I see... we weren't taught this definition of closure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can be called as an answer :

Here is my idea :

You want to find smallest closed set which contains $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ name it $\bar{A}$

For all good reasons, I can say that your $\bar{A}$ has to be a subset of $[0,1]$ (???)

So, you have to see if some element of $[0,1]$ is missing in the closure...

Suppose $a\in [0,1]$ is missed in the closure.. then?

I would go further and claim that if some thing is missing that can not be a rational number.. (????)

May be you can say no irrational number is missing (:D) by using density of rational numbers...