# What is closure $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

What is closure of $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$ ?

It is subset of $\Bbb Q$ so its closure should be $\Bbb R$ but I'm confused here it is somewhere dense or everywhere dense.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1930817 or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/700493.

Comment: Why do you think closure should be $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @Pax Daga,  because it is subset of $\Bbb Q$ and closure of $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the closure with the standar topology of $\mathbb{R}$

$\overline{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]} \subseteq \overline{\mathbb{Q}} \cap \overline{[0,1]}=\mathbb{R}\cap [0,1] = [0,1]$

now because $ [0,1] \subseteq \overline{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]} $ we get

the closure is $ [0,1]$

Comment: Note that the question has been asked and answered before.

Comment: I know, but those answers aren't satisfying for me, I would say they are confusing even, I know because I was in the confusing position of OP not long ago, i believe this answer is simple and quick, easy to grasp for someone who trying to understand about the closure and how to work some exercises.